# Firebase missing dSYMs after upload-symbols was successful

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

The Firebase Crashlytics console says I have unprocessed crashes from one missing dSym. When I click on it, it says that `<Some-UUID>.dsym` is Required.

I ran `Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp Somewear/GoogleService-Info-release.plist -p ios appDsyms.zip` and can see that the exact `<Some-UUID>.dsym` file was uploaded successfully in the script output. I ran it on dsyms downloaded from the App Store > Test Flight > Latest Prod Version > Build Metadata.

I waited an hour and it still complains about the missing dsym, and the same file still says "Required".

Answer (score 4):

Update: I filed a support ticket with the Firebase team. The next day, I saw they responded saying they didn't see the missing dsym. Sure enough, I opened Crashlytics and suddenly I didn't see the missing dsym error and all my latest crashes were processed.

When the support staff emailed me the didn't see the missing dSym, that was about 2 hours after I ran the upload. I see other posts saying they checked the next day.

My advice would be to **wait 2-24 hours** after running upload-symbols, although this is very frustrating if you have urgent crashes needing attention with a new release.